# multicolumn within the header of a longtabu and throw \omit errors

Tags: tabu, multicolumn

I've run into an error while using `longtabu`. I have an example of it working fine without `\multicolumn` in the header, and not working when I have a `\multicolumn` in the header.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=4cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth{|c|c|X|c|}
\hline
\rowfont\bfseries
\rowcolor{lightgray}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{From / To} & Description & Cost \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{(continued)}\\
\hline
\rowfont\bfseries
\rowcolor{lightgray}
From & To & Description & Cost \\
\hline
\endhead
\rowfont\bfseries
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\cellcolor{cyan}DAY 1 -- 2012-10-15} \\
\hline
1:00 & 2:00 & Action & \\
\hline
1:00 & 2:00 & Action & \\
\hline
\end{longtabu}

\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth{|c|c|X|c|}
\hline
\rowfont\bfseries
\rowcolor{lightgray}
From & To & Description & Cost \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{(continued)}\\
\hline
\rowfont\bfseries
\rowcolor{lightgray}
From & To & Description & Cost \\
\hline
\endhead
\rowfont\bfseries
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\cellcolor{cyan}DAY 1 -- 2012-10-15} \\
\hline
1:00 & 2:00 & Action & \\
\hline
1:00 & 2:00 & Action & \\
\hline
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

Table 1 throws errors, Table 2 works fine. The only difference between the two is the use of `\multicolumn` in Table 1 in the header. I have tested with `\multicolumn` in firsthead and head separately and in both, and the same error is thrown.

```
! Misplaced \omit.
\multispan ->\omit 
               \@multispan 
l.33   \end{longtabu}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Probably it ought to work, but as it doesn't you can use

```
\hline
\rowfont\bfseries
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{lightgray}From / To} & \cellcolor{lightgray}Description &\cellcolor{lightgray} Cost \\
\hline
\endfirsthead
```

Comment: It reduced the number of errors in my actual code, so this is definitely on the right path! Thanks!